# How to grant access to android app users for AWS S3 Objects?

Tags: android, json, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I have a bucket in Amazon S3 and I have Lambda functions that generates JSON files for this bucket. I am using the S3 files in my mobile app. Until recently, I gave public access to these S3 files for simplicity. But now I want these S3 objects to be accessible with a simple authentication. I’ve examined all AWS tutorials but couldn’t find an easy way to implement this. I don’t want to use Cognito service since my app doesn’t need authentication and since my S3 files are not user-related, they are used for app. I want these S3 objects to be accessible by http request to a url which includes simple key like this:

```
https://s3.eu-central-1.amazonaws.com/<bucket name>/<object name>?<key>
```

where key can be a combination of region, aws access key, secret access key or other values of the user that i define (I am using Retrofit to fetch json data from S3 bucket)  I’ve looked at the presigned url option but an example for android-sdk doesn’t exists there, and most of the methods that can be used for this purpose are deprecated. Isn’t there an easy way for this? Or should I host my json files in other service/place?

Answer (score 4):

If you say no to Cognito then you are just complicating things for yourself. This is exactly the case where you want to use Cognito. The fact that you don't require your users to authenticate and that the S3 content is not user specific doesn't mean that Cognito is not suitable in this scenario.

All you have to do is to create Cognito identity pool and choose to support unauthenticated entities. Create an IAM policy that allows reading from that specific S3 bucket and let unauthenticated users to assume that IAM role by attaching it to those unauthenticated entities.

Authentication then happens automatically during the initialization of SDK in your application. That is all that you need to do to allow access to that S3 bucket only from your application.

And you get access metrics even for unauthenticated users as a bonus. And if you later decide that you want your application to support authentication as well, then you don't need to change almost anything in your setup.

Comment: You are saying that Cognito is the easiest way (which i found complicated) Ok then, i will try, thanks.

Comment: @HüseyinŞahin Give it a shot, you will not want to use anything else once you figure it out.

Comment: Thanks for the outright answer. I wasn't sure if I should use cognito but this convinced me. Now cognito is running neatly.